# Using MSBuild Conditions on COMReferences

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, conditional-compilation

How can I specify a [Condition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7szfhaft.aspx) for a COMReference in my *.csproj file? The following does not appear to work:

```
<COMReference Include="SomeComLib" Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Debug' ">
    ...
</COMReference>
```

I have some COM references in a C# project in Visual Studio 2008. I would like them to automatically use non-isolation mode when I am in Debug, but automatically switch to Isolation mode when I make a Release build. I thought I could achieve this by specifying two different COMReferences in my *.csproj file, which are selected based on the Condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your strategy should work, but if not, you could also move the Condition to the ItemGroup that encloses the ComReferences.

Comment: I discovered that I can even put the Condition on the Isolated element. Visual Studio does not update the value in the Properties pane when I switch between Debug and Release, but when I build it does the right thing.